# Algorithm Complexity for runtime involving 2 seperate variables

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have an algorithm that runs in a<sup>b</sup> time where a and b are both separate inputs.

Is my algorithm polynomial time complexity algorithm still or is it n<sup>n</sup>? I think n<sup>n</sup> is non polynomial but I am still not sure about that as well.

I see factorial of n algorithm still evaluates to n<sup>n</sup> complexity so n<sup>n</sup> must be non polynomial too. Please help and clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `b` is part of the input, your running time is not polynomial. (Try giving the degree of the polynomial that bounds it!)

In some areas, special subproblems are studied (graphs with bounded degree come to mind, or packing with a constant number of sizes)  so you cay say that yes, *for a fixed b* your algorithm is polynomial *in a*.